# Laravel with IIS, routing problems

Tags: php, laravel, iis

My problem is that my routes in web.php are not working properly.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Sends me here 
https://ibb.co/SXW19fw

It should show me the Laravel landing page

```
Route::get('/test/', function () {
    echo "Welcome";
});
```

The second one gives HTTP 500.19 — Internal Server Error
https://ibb.co/JmW816g

Here is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

My IIS configuration
https://ibb.co/fSZqr7T

Comment: Could you please tell me how you install or publish the lavel application on the IIS? Do you install it in the default web sites or create a new web sites?  Could you please convert the 500 error details error message to English?

Comment: https://jimfrenette.com/2016/09/laravel-iis-windows-install/ , this should help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it , IIS didnt have PHP module

Comment: what PHP module?

Answer (score 0):

I have it working with the below config in my public folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <remove name="Imported Rule 2-1" />
                <remove name="Imported Rule 1-1" />
                <remove name="Imported Rule 1" />
                <remove name="Imported Rule 2" />
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.+)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```